# How to create a checkout with Shopify API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Through Postman, I am sending GraphQL to the appropriate endpoint in line with this page of the Shopify docs: [Create a checkout with the Storefront API](https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/checkout). I am getting the following response:

```
{
    "errors": "[API] This action requires merchant approval for write_checkouts scope."
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me because I have enabled the checkouts permission as seen here:
[image]

If the app needs to be converted to a sales channel or public app, please let me know how that can be done. Thanks for any help!

Comment: hello Chirs, how did you fix it, thank you?

Comment: would be better if you post your answer!

Comment: @Ericgit I never found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with Private or Custom Apps. Your app must be Public.
Some additional information here:
https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/how-to-grant-write-checkouts-permission/td-p/448587

Requirements section of the following link mentions your app must be public:
https://shopify.dev/apps/channels/getting-started

On second thought, there is createCart for StoreFront API:
https://shopify.dev/custom-storefronts/cart#create-a-cart-and-add-a-line-item

I created a private app and used the following:

Post: https://[storename].myshopify.com/api/2021-10/graphql.json

Add Header: X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token:somevalue

Set body:

```
mutation MyMutation1 {
   
  cartCreate(input: {lines: {merchandiseId: "someproducytid==",quantity:1}, buyerIdentity: {email: "test@test.com"}}) {
    cart {
      id
      checkoutUrl
      buyerIdentity {
        customer {
          email
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```